# Loading local package using Composer (PHP)

Tags: composer-php

I can't load a local class using composer.

The directory structure and key files are as follows:

```
/vendor/pisukes/hello-world/composer.json
/vendor/pisukes/hello-world/src/HelloWorld.php
/vendor/autoload.php
/html/index.php
/composer.json
```

Composer.json under hello-world:

```
{
    "name": "pisukes/hello-world",
    "type": "library",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",    
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "HelloWorld\\": "src/"
        }
    }       
}
```

Composer.json under root:

```
{    
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "./vendor/pisukes/hello-world"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "pisukes/hello-world": "@dev"
    }
}
```

The output of "composer update" shows no errors:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

HelloWorld.php:

```
namespace HelloWorld;

class SayHello
{
    public static function world()
    {
        return 'Hello World!';
    }

}
```

index.php:

```
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
use HelloWorld\SayHello;
echo SayHello::world();
```

When I run "php index.php", I get a class not found error:
*PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'HelloWorld\SayHello'*

If I move HelloWorld.php to the /html directory and update the require_once statement accordingly, I get the expected output...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem using:
*composer dumpautoload **-o***

Note that I've tried 'composer dumpautoload' but was not successful, I needed to use the flag ***-o*** to make it work.

As per Composer help:
-o, --optimize Optimizes PSR0 and PSR4 packages to be loaded with classmaps too, good for production